# Is it still useful to declare development dependencies in a gemspec when using bundler?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am working on a new Ruby Gem. I am familiar with using Bundler to manage gems:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gemspec

gem 'rspec-rails'
```

I am familiar with specifying dependencies in a gemspec file:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # ...
  s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 4.1.5"
end
```

The Gemfile that was generated mentions that I should move my dependency declarations from my Gemfile to my gemspec when I'm ready to release.

```
# Declare any dependencies that are still in development here instead of in
# your gemspec. These might include edge Rails or gems from your path or
# Git. Remember to move these dependencies to your gemspec before releasing
# your gem to rubygems.org.
```

Why would I want to do this? Why should my gemspec care what gems I'm using in development? What purpose does `development_dependency` serve that Bundler doesn't already do for me?

Answer (score 5):

To best answer your questions, we should first untangle the concepts of Bundler and Rubygems. I think a great explanation can be [found here](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/).

### Why Would I Want to [move dependencies from Gemfile to .gemspec]?

Gemfile allows you to specify not only dependencies, but [where the dependencies come from](http://bundler.io/git.html). This is useful when you are also working on the dependencies themselves and need to point to a Git repo (or something).

Once work on these dependencies is complete, Rubygem conventions dictate that you move the dependency declaration on these released gems into your .gemspec file. Adding a line `gemspec` tells Bundler to read from this conventional Rubygems location. If you are working on a gem, and you are not actively developing the gem's dependencies, then all dependencies should be declared in your .gemspec

### Why should my gemspec care what gems I'm using in development?

From [the docs](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/) for `add_development_dependency`:

> Development dependencies aren't installed by default and aren't activated when a gem is required.

A popular example for this Rspec. You should generally declare Rspec as a development dependency for yourself, but not force everyone else to download it when they grab your gem.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the comment you cited does not say "development dependencies", it says "dependencies that are in development". Dependencies that are in development commonly include cutting-edge versions of gems that you are installing directly from a Git repo. RubyGems cannot install gems from a Git repo; however, Bundler can. If you are installing cutting-edge versions of gems installed from a source that RubyGems cannot handle (such as a VCS repo), you should list them in your `Gemfile` instead of the `.gemspec` file.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for clarifying that. I'm still not sure if declaring development dependencies in the gemspec is preferred or if this practice has been superseded by using Bundler.

Comment: @Andrew: You should still declare development dependencies in the gemspec, so they can be installed via RubyGems.

Comment: I thought that development dependencies are not installed when you install a gem. Is that not true?

Comment: @Andrew: Not by default, but they optionally can be.